# MySQL: What's wrong with this CREATE PROCEDURE statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreateTopic;
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTopic
(
   i_forum_id INT,
   i_user_id INT,
   i_title VARCHAR(255),
   i_language VARCHAR(50),
   i_content TEXT,
   i_stickied TINYINT,
   i_announce TINYINT,
   i_closed TINYINT
)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO forum_topics (forum_id, user_id, title, language)
       VALUES (i_forum_id, i_user_id, i_title, i_language);
   SET @tid := LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO forum_posts (topic_id, user_id, subject, content) VALUES (@tid, i_user_id, i_title, i_content);
   INSERT INTO core_logs (obj_id, user_id, type, action) VALUES (@tid, i_user_id, 'Topics', 'Topic Created');
END;
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with it. MySQL tells me all sorts of things are incorrect, it just doesn't want to be created. Also, the parameters are identical types and lengths to their respective  tables.

Comment: Give us some more details please of all the errors

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://gyazo.com/be0034c6d9638a61f9f13fe30d07e87e.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is your first ";" that breaks procedure definition and mysql thinks you are done and treats whatever goes after ";" as another query. 
You have to use delimiter for stored procedures.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreateTopic$$
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTopic
(
   i_forum_id INT,
   i_user_id INT,
   i_title VARCHAR(255),
   i_language VARCHAR(50),
   i_content TEXT,
   i_stickied TINYINT,
   i_announce TINYINT,
   i_closed TINYINT
)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO forum_topics (forum_id, user_id, title, language)
       VALUES (i_forum_id, i_user_id, i_title, i_language);
   SET @tid := LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO forum_posts (topic_id, user_id, subject, content) VALUES (@tid, i_user_id, i_title, i_content);
   INSERT INTO core_logs (obj_id, user_id, type, action) VALUES (@tid, i_user_id, 'Topics', 'Topic Created');
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems.  I hope I got them all:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreateTopic;
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTopic
(
   i_forum_id INT,
   i_user_id INT,
   i_title VARCHAR(255),
   i_language VARCHAR(50),
   i_content TEXT,
   i_stickied TINYINT,
   i_announce TINYINT,
   i_closed TINYINT
)
BEGIN
   DECLARE tid INT;
   INSERT INTO forum_topics (`forum_id`, `user_id`, `title`, `language`)
       VALUES (i_forum_id, i_user_id, i_title, i_language);
   SET tid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO forum_posts (`topic_id`, `user_id`, `subject`, `content`) VALUES (tid, i_user_id, i_title, i_content);
   INSERT INTO core_logs (`obj_id`, `user_id`, `type`, `action`) VALUES (tid, i_user_id, 'Topics', 'Topic Created');
END;
```

Comment: `:=` is short-forum for declaring and setting. Anyway, your fix is also giving me an error: http://gyazo.com/d618df714a31b58003e58f5494a6afaf.png

Comment: You need to change the delimiter using to something other than `;` before the `CREATE` and back to `;` after the `END`.  See the examples here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: There's a screenshot attached to my comment above.

Comment: @Chris Morgan, error 1: http://gyazo.com/05e0a831f4ca6dcfc5f56ca4d9b8c160.png, error 2: http://gyazo.com/4b5260a317e46e62f1f77e9bc79d66c2.png. It definitely made it bigger, but I still can't find the error.

Comment: When I execute the code I provided in MySQL, I get a `Table 'core_logs' doesn't exist` - I was hoping that meant the code would compile against your database.  The specific error you get with this code (I don't need a screenshot) would be helpful.

Comment: ok... @chris was correct about the delimiter... I added `DELIMITER $$` before `CREATE PROCEDURE` and changed `END;` to `END $$`.  I also created the tables in a test database and CreateTopic was created so it should work for you.

Comment: @Dark You need to put the `DROP` before the delimiter change if you want to use `;`